# How to attach an object's function to a Dio.js event?

Tags: javascript

[The Dio.js GitHub page](https://github.com/thysultan/dio.js)

[My Dio.js issue on github with owner's suggestion that didn't work](https://github.com/thysultan/dio.js/issues/85)

The goal is to render dom elements and attach an event that is in the same object as the render function

When the webpage loads, I call an init function that render some divs and attach a click event to a function in the same object.

```
var thecheckbox = (function() {
  function x() {}

  x.prototype.isActivated = false // True when the user click the checkbox
  x.prototype.init = function() {
    let bodydiv = document.createElement('div')
    document.body.appendChild(bodydiv)


    d.render(this.render, bodydiv)
  }
  x.prototype.init = function() {
    let mybody = document.createElement('div')
    document.body.appendChild(mybody)


    d.render(this.render, protekBody)
  }
  x.prototype.activate = function() {
    console.log('Activate')
    var _this = this
    if (!_this.isActivated) {
      _this.isActivated = true
      var checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox')[0]
      checkbox.getElementsByClassName(
        'checkbox2'
      )[0].style.display = 'block'

    }
  }
  x.prototype.render = function() {
    var _this = this
    return d.h(
      'div',
      { class: 'normal light' },
      d.h(
        'div',
        {
          class: 'content'
        },
        d.h(
          'div',
          {
            class: 'inline-block',
            onClick: this.activate // <<<---------
          },

        ),
        d.h(
          'div',
          { class: 'inline-block' },
          d.h(
            'div',
            { class: 'center' },
            d.h('div', { class: 'label center' }, strings.checkme)
          )
        )
      )
    )
  }

  return new x()
})()

// Initialize
_addEvent(document, 'ready', function() {
  thecheckbox.init()
})
```

I talked to the owner of the repo here (https://github.com/thysultan/dio.js/issues/85) and it still doesn't work as he explained.

I need to be able to access the object's properties outside the scope of Dio but attach an event to a dio dom element.

I tried converting the object to a regular object (not instantiated) and call `d.render(d.h(thecheckbox), mydiv)` but it doesn't works.

Comment: I am not certain of the context where you are working, but in the block you point to you are referencing `this` rather than `_this`. This could be why you don't get to access `this.activate`

Comment: @Moustachiste Thanks for your comment. Sorry for the confusion, it's because I've tried both. `TypeError: object is undefined; can't access its "then" property` thrown by dio.js function: `function thenable(object) {
      return (
        typeof object.then === 'function' && typeof object.catch === 'function'
      )
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@HypeWolf

Maybe you could try the following:

```
function x() {
  this.activate = this.activate.bind(this)
}
```

or as alternative:

```
onClick: () => this.activate()
```

And I think you should also do something like:

```
d.render(() => this.render(), protekBody)
```